# Authentification Required In my website

Tags: php, html, web

I have a problem. 
I have this website [Saniprof](http://www.saniprof.com.mx)

And its in php.
Everytime I try to check the website throws a Authentification Required, and I don't know why. 
Is the same code.

Is a simple website, and that doesn't happen in the other pages in the website.

Im using this code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

Comment: If you don't use authentication, then disable Windows Authentication in IIS.

Comment: The thing is, I only have access by ftp. and I can't do a lot. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and resolved the issue with this solution. put below configuration in `web.config`
It will allow to all user.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" /> 
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```